# add new item button of 2 document libraries in a sharepoint page

Tags: document-library, jslink, client-side-rendering

I want to have 2 new item buttons of document libraries in a sharepoint page

I tried copying the entire html of that element and adding it in the page, but that doesn't seem to work

How I can have the new item button added to sharepoint pages?

Comment: pls mark my answer if I have solved your problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you want to have one SharePoint page where you want to keep 2 separate buttons for 2 different Document Libraries. If yes, you can add two List view web parts with reference to your libraries. 
Action plan:
Edit Page --> Insert a web part --> choose you 2 Libraries under "Apps" section. 
After this you can insert a Script Editor web part and hide the unwanted buttons using below style:

```
<style type=text/css>
#QCB1_Button2, #QCB1_Button3, #QCB1_Button4, #QCB1_Button5{
    display: none;
}
#QCB2_Button2, #QCB2_Button3, #QCB2_Button4, #QCB2_Button5{
    display: none;
}
</style>
```

[image: This is how 2 libraries will be displayed]